# How do I get the data or message from my service?

Tags: java, android, firebase

My MyFirebaseMessagingService.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService 
 extends FirebaseMessagingService {

 private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FRCM:"+ remoteMessage.getFrom());

         /*Check if the message contains data*/
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message data: "+ remoteMessage.getData());

        }
        /*Check if the message contains notification*/
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message body: "+ remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());


        }
    }
    /*Display Notification Body*/
    private void sendNotification(String body) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        /*Set sound of Notification*/

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event_note_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0/*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
         intent = new Intent("myAction");
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

and My Activity Messaging is.

```
public class Mess{
}
```

Comment: from where are you sending a notification?

Comment: to my Message Activity named Mess.. how should i get the data from my FirebaseMessagingService....

Answer (score 0):

You send messages from your phone using FCM. You need to make a `POST` to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` api with payload that you want to send, and you server key found in Firebase Console project or You can Use POSTMAN google chrome extension

As an exameple of payload sending to a single user with `to` param:

```
{ "data": {
      "score": "5x1",
      "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Also, `to` param can be used for topics `"to": "topics/yourTopic"`

In `data` you can send whatever you want, message is received in `onMessageReceived()` service from Firebase.

More details you can found in Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

Comment: no i mean how to get the data that receive from firebasecloudmessaging and pass to my activity.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data to another activity

```
 private void sendNotification(String body) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
```

here you can set intent

```
 intent.putExtra("word", body);
```

and to read from activity use

```
 b = getIntent().getExtras();
 String passed_from = b.getString("word");
```